# Удалить объект или инициализировать его заново

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Всех приветствую,
есть такой винтажный плеер: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/07/12/old-school-cassette-player-with-html5-audio/.
Загрузка композиций в нем происходит при создании объекта через передачу options:

```
$( '#vc-container' ).cassette(options);
```

В самой функции cassette происходит инициализация объекта через this._init:

```
$.Cassette= function( options, element ) {  
    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );      };
```

Данный метод описан в прототипе:

```
$.Cassette.prototype    = {
    _init: function( options ) {
            // код.........

            }    }
```

**Задача**: не перегружая страницу обновить переменную options в объекте, и заново объект инициализировать.

Я вижу два варианта решения:

1. Удалить объект и заново его создать с новыми параметрами. Но не понимаю как его можно удалить.
2. Передать новые параметры запущенному объекту.
   В коде прототипа делаю ссылку на него извне: `window.myOb=this;`
   Потом создаю новый объект-массив `options={ songs: [ '333','222','777', '777', '888']};`

Пытаюсь его инициализировать `myOb.__proto__._init(options);`
Но создается другой объект. И старый существует.

Если же делать через повторный запуск функции (передачу нового массива),
перед этим удалив тег audio:

```
    $( '#vc-container' ).cassette(options);
```

то создается (появляется?) объект с первоначальными параметрами options.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении надо искать решение данной задачи?

Comment: опиши подробнее, что именно ты хочешь изменить. Только список песен?

Comment: менять список песен, и соответственно при смене списка кассета должна становится в первоначальное положение. Слева вся пленка, справа пустой ролик.
Первоначальную ошибку я свою нашел: window.myOb=this; я получил ссылку в прототипе, а не в классе.  Это поправил и получается теперь я могу получать доступ к свойствам и методам. До этого я имея ссылку на прототип, каждый раз менял, что то в нем создавая новый объект. Поэтому и было засорение объектов.
Теперь осталось разобраться только в поиске инициализации первоначального положения кассеты.

Comment: самый простой способ был бы: удаление объекта и создание нового с новым списком. Но как удалять объект я пока не понимаю.

Comment: Ничего не понятно кроме первых двух предложений в большом комментарии. Удалить ты можешь целиком элемент. Затем добавить такой же новый, и применить к нему `$(newElement).cassete(options)`. Но если смотреть исходники можно есть метод очистки `_clear`, а так же можно выставить вручную конкретную позицию: `_setSidesPosStatus`

Comment: т.е. при удалении элемента объект также удаляется? Страница каталога кассет будет реализована на ajax и не хотелось бы забивать память множеством объектов у же не связанных с элементами.
За _clear и _setSidesPosStatus  спасибо большое. Попробую сегодня.

Comment: Тот объект, который ты имеешь ввиду, кладется в `data` элемента, для которого ты вызываешь плагин. Соответственно при удалении элемента, с которым связан объект плагина, сам плагин так же удаляется

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все ясно стало. Я просто не понимал как обращаться к объекту. Не мог понять, что указывает на него. Поэтому и создал в теле cassete(options) следующую переменную: `window.myOb=this;` чтобы потом через нее обращаться к объекту.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, если уж писать, то, быть может, модифицировать код плеера, добавив в него метод переопределения свойств конкретного инстанса.

Иначе, без документации - копать сорцы и искать куда и как пишутся опции.
Вероятнее всего, лежат в свойствах самого объекта, а значит - либо писать внешний метод, редактирующий их нужным образом, либо внутренний. (см.предложение выше)

Comment: Похоже, так и придется.